# If a plane "takes off" and a boat "sails" what does a train/subway train do?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Example sentence:

> When the subway train __ , I wasn't clutching a grab handle, so I almost fell to the floor.

What's the verb to describe a train/subway train "taking off"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[depart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/depart)** is probably the best word to describe a train leaving a station, but in this context you are probably more interested in the fact that the train **started moving**, because this is more important to the story (which is about nearly falling over) than the fact that the train was leaving a station.

---

Note that **[clutching](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clutch)** suggests a very tight, or even desparate, grip... for example in the expression

> [A drowning man will clutch at a straw](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+drowning+man+will+clutch+at+a+straw)

Simply **holding** would be better in this context.

Comment: +1 **Started Moving** is the correct phrase for this particular example.  In general, trains **roll**.

Comment: @Peter: **rolled** in relation to trains may be more widely used in the US (think Frankie Laine's Rawhide) than in the UK. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=train+rolled%3A+eng_us_2012%2Ctrain+rolled%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrain%20rolled%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrain%20rolled%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In the context of the OP's sentence, you can also use "set into motion".

Comment: I disagree.  Planes and boats also depart.  Planes depart an airport and boats depart a pier/dock.  The requested comparison asks for an action specific to trains.

Comment: @EllieK, I don't see the word "specific" in the question. Furthermore, I don't think there's a specific word for trains.

Comment: @JavaLatte The question title is specific enough without the word "specific".

Comment: @JavaLatte See Jason's answer for trains.

Answer (score 1):

A train [pulls away from the station](http://pull%20away%20from%20the%20station).

Comment: That is exactly what trains do!

Comment: The phrase is well enough understood that one can drop "from the station."  It is implied.  This results in a usage such as, "I had to run to make the train, boarding just as it was pulling away."  No mention of the station is necessary for understanding.